# How does the estaurine turbidity maximum vary depending on the type of estuary?

Tags: ocean, rivers, estuary, turbidity

An estuarine turbidity maximum (ETM) is the area of an estuary that has maximum values in suspended particles in the water column. My questions are

- What are the main characteristics of the ETM?
- How does the ETM affect biological organisms?
- How do the characteristics of the ETM vary depending on the type of estuary (salt-wedged, well-mixed, partially mixed)?